# Formula of selecting random elements from a generated pool of elements

Tags: probability, statistics

Since I am not good at math and would like to know something, I ask here. I hope that this question can't be easy solved with Google, because I really have no idea how to call such a calculation to google except probability calculation.

Here is my problem:
I have a selection pool full of names, from which I select X times (without double selection).

The selection pool is filled as follows:
There are for example 10 names. Each name has its own probability to get into the selection pool.

Let us assume that I have these names as an example:

- Name 1 to 5 = 100%
- Name 6 = 50%
- Name 7 = 20%
- Name 8 = 80%
- Name 9 = 90%
- Name 10 = 10%

And in this case I choose a total of 5 names. How high is the probability for each name to be drawn at the end?

And if I would add the name "name 11" with a probability of 5% to the list of names, how would the probability be calculated? Can you put this into a formula?

---

**Edit:**
Forgott to write it but the selection pool is only filled one time at the beginning and not after each selection.

**Edit2:**
The actual case is that when the pool is empty, a new one is generated and the remaining selections are filled. In this case it is possible that double names occur when another pool is generated. But to keep it simple here, I would say that there are simply no more selections than there are names with 100% probability

**Edit3:**

I hope that this example will help me to explain it again in an understandable way.

Let us assume we have `n` pieces of paper, in this case 10, with names 1 to 10 on them. Each piece of paper has a `probability` to come in a basket. These are the probabilities:

- Name 1 to 5 = 100%
- Name 6 = 50%
- Name 7 = 20%
- Name 8 = 80%
- Name 9 = 90%
- Name 10 = 10%

Now the content of the basket (pool) is generated. Since names 1 to 5 have a probability of 100%, they are placed directly into the basket. Now a D10 die is rolled for name 6 and if it is 5 or lower, the name is placed in the basket. For name 7 it must be 2 or less, and so on.

At the end we have a basket with `X` pieces of paper with names in it and now we draw `Y` times a piece of paper, in this example we draw 5 pieces. How high is the probability that note 6 is in the `Y` (5) drawings?

Extra points are given if you can take into account that if the number of draws exceeds the number of cards in the basket, the basket will be regenerated and the remaining draws will be made.

**Edit4:**

I have wrote a little program to simulate this and this are the probabilities that i want to calculate and my simlutaions says:

After 100.000.000 interations with 5 draws:

- Name 1 to 5 (100%) = 67%
- Name 6 (50%) = 31%
- Name 7 (20%) = 12%
- Name 8 (80%) = 52%
- Name 9 (90%) = 59%
- Name 10 (10%) = 6%

shitty program (writen in nodejs as .ts):

```
var names = [
    {count: 0, prob: 100},
    {count: 0, prob: 100},
    {count: 0, prob: 100},
    {count: 0, prob: 100},
    {count: 0, prob: 100},
    {count: 0, prob: 50},
    {count: 0, prob: 20},
    {count: 0, prob: 80},
    {count: 0, prob: 90},
    {count: 0, prob: 10}
];
var turns = 100000000;

function getRandomInt(max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max)) + 1;
}

for(var i = 0; i < turns; i++){
    var nameIndex = 0;
    var pool = [];
    for(let name of names) {
        if(name.prob >= getRandomInt(100)){
            pool.push(names.indexOf(name));
        }
        nameIndex++;
    }
    var randomDraws = [];
    for(var draw = 0; draw < 5; draw++){
        var randomNum = getRandomInt(pool.length) - 1;
        if(randomDraws.includes(randomNum)) {
            while(true){
                randomNum = getRandomInt(pool.length) - 1;
                if(!randomDraws.includes(randomNum)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        randomDraws.push(randomNum);
    }


    for(let drawIndex of randomDraws) {
        names[pool[drawIndex]].count++;
    }
}
for(let name of names) {
    var percentage = Math.floor((name.count / turns) * 100);
    console.log("Probability: " + name.prob + "%. Actually Probability: " + percentage + "%")
}
```

**Edit5:**

@Ethan Bolker was rigth. It is selecting random elements from a weighted list. I still have no clue if this can be solved with a function or if its only possible to simulate it with a program.

Here is some python code, that delivers the sam results as the typescript code above:

```
import random
import math
nameCounts = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
nameList = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", "Name7", "Name8", "Name9", "Name10"]
weights = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 20, 80, 90, 10]

indexList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

cycles = 10000000

for x in range(cycles):
    randomSelection = random.choices(indexList, weights=weights, k=5)

    for val in randomSelection:
        nameCounts[val] += 1

for x in range(10):
    percentage = math.floor((nameCounts[x] / cycles) * 100)
    print(str(nameList[x]) + " with weight " + str(weights[x]) + ": " + str(percentage) + "%")
```

**Edit6:**

The python script only allows selecting from a list up to 10 elements. I dont know why but the list I want to use could be longer than that.

**Edit7:**

I guess the important variables are:

- Total count of elements = **count**
- Weight/probalility of each element = **weight**
- Elements to be selected = **selections**

Basic examples (simulated with 50.000.000 cycles):

count = 2, weight = [100%, 50%], selections = 1:

- 100% weight = 75.00% probability
- 50% weight = 25.00% probability

count = 3, weight = [100%, 50%, 50%], selections = 1:

- 100% weight = 58.33% probability
- 50% weight = 20.83% probability
- 50% weight = 20.83% probability

count = 4, weight = [100%, 50%, 50%, 50%], selections = 1:

- 100% weight = 46.865% probability
- 50% weight = 17.723% probability
- 50% weight = 17.705% probability
- 50% weight = 17.705% probability

count = 3, weight = [100%, 100%, 50%], selections = 1:

- 100% weight = 41.66% probability
- 100% weight = 41.66% probability
- 50% weight = 16.66% probability

count = 3, weight = [100%, 100%, 50%], selections = 2:

- 100% weight = 83.33% probability
- 100% weight = 83.33% probability
- 50% weight = 33.33% probability

Comment: Without knowing all the names in the pool, do you at least know how many are there in the selection pool?

Comment: @MathLover The names in the pool are created with the list of all names. Name 1 to 5 have a 100% probability to get into the pool. Name 6 has a 60% probability to get into the pool etc. And then I select X name from the pool.

Comment: But how do you know you can select $10$ names? Given we have 100% probability for only $5$ names and rest of them being lower probability, it is possible that only first $5$ names get into the pool.

Comment: @MathLover The actual case is that when the pool is empty, a new one is generated and the remaining selections are filled. In this case it is possible that double names occur when another pool is generated. But to keep it simple here, I would say that there are simply no more selections than there are names with 100% probability.

Comment: I _think_ you can treat the problem as selecting $5$ tickets from a set of $10$ tickets with weights $1,1,1,1,1,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.9,0.1$. That might make both simulation and mathematical analysis easier. I've no time to work out the details.

Comment: I don't think this is equivalent to the weighted case, at least, the weighted case where probability is the rescaled weight.  E.g. consider $\{1, 0.5\}$ and you draw only one ticket.  In the weighted case the prob for drawing the second is $1/3$, but in the OP setting the prob for drawing the second is $1/4$ ($1/2$ for it to be include, then $1/2$ to pick it when included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculations are tedious, but you can ask a computer program to do them. The algorithm finds the exact answer in fractional form. (There's a formula, but the formula doesn't simplify especially well.)

$$\begin{array}{l|cccccccccc}\text{Gen prob} & 1 & 1&1&1&1& 0.5 &0.2 & 0.8 & 0.9 & 0.1\\\hline \text{Selection prob } &\frac{1703341}{2520000} & \frac{1703341}{2520000} & \frac{1703341}{2520000} & \frac{1703341}{2520000} & \frac{1703341}{2520000} & \frac{396911}{1260000} & \frac{306337}{2520000} & \frac{330553}{630000} & \frac{83859}{140000} & \frac{75731}{1260000} \\
&0.675928 &0.675928 &0.675928 &0.675928 &0.675928 &0.315008 &0.121562 &0.524687 &0.598992 &0.060103
\end{array}$$

Here is the program:

```
from math import prod
from fractions import Fraction
def bitstrings(n) :
    """Return all possible bitstrings of length n"""
    if n == 0 :
        yield []
        return
    else :
        for b in [0,1] :
            for x in bitstrings(n-1) :
                yield [b] + x


def prob_selected(weights, num_selected = 5) :

    # P(n generated, including e)*P(e of n selected | n generated including e)
    # i.e. Sum_n (n generated, including e) * #num_selections / #generated
    # num_selected = how many will be drawn out of the hat (at most)

    n = len(weights)
    final_probability = [0] * n
    
    for bits in bitstrings(n) :
        num_generated = sum(bits)
        prob_generated = prod([w if b else (1-w) for (w,b) in zip(weights, bits)])
        
        for i in range(n) :
            if bits[i] :
                final_probability[i] += prob_generated * min(num_selected, num_generated) / num_generated
    return final_probability


print(prob_selected([1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                     0.5, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1]))

print(prob_selected([1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                     Fraction(1,2), Fraction(2,10), Fraction(8,10), Fraction(9,10), Fraction(1,10)]))
```

Basically, the algorithm iterates over all possible contents you could generate in the hat. It computes the probability of those contents and counts the number of things $m$ in the hat. If you take that probability times 5/$m$ (where 5 is the number of things you'll draw from the hat), you get the probability that when you draw 5 things from the hat, a specific element is among them. (It's the same probability for every element in the hat.)  You keep a running tally of each element's probability of being generated and then drawn, adding all of them up to get a final answer. I use the fraction module to get exact answers in fraction form.

It might make it more readable if I renamed the variable bits to be is_in_hat.

---

If you want a mathematical formula for computing the probability $P_i$ that the $i$th element is drawn given the weights $W_i$, here it is:

$$P_i = \sum_{\text{all possible}\\\text{hat contents}\\S} \left(\prod_{k\in S} W_k\right)\left(\prod_{k\notin S}(1-W_k) \right) \cdot \frac{5}{|S|} \cdot I(i \in S) $$

Here, $S$ is a set of indexes like $\{1,4,5\}$, and $|S|$ is the size of the set. The expression $I(i \in S)$ is equal to 1 (if $i\in S$) or 0 (if $i \notin S$).

I personally prefer the computer program over the formula.

Comment: everything works fine with that code but I have run into some troubles. I got that problem that the list of weights can be as long as 60 weigths so the calculation cant be done doe to the large amount of possibilities. Do you know if the is then even possible to calculate? here is my question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64567680/calculate-a-large-ammount-without-running-out-of-memory

Answer (score 1):

You can start by applying Bayes' theorem to identify the structure of the solution.

For name $N$, we have:

$P(N\mathrm{\ chosen})=\dfrac{P(N\mathrm{\ in\ list})P(N\mathrm{\ chosen}|N\mathrm{\ in\ list})}{P(N\mathrm{\ in\ list}|N\mathrm{\ chosen})}\tag{1}$

- Note that $P(N\mathrm{\ in\ list}|N\mathrm{\ chosen})=1$, so we can get rid of that.
- $P(N\mathrm{\ in\ list})$ is fixed up front, as a part of the inputs.
- Initially I thought that $P(N\ \mathrm{chosen}|N\mathrm{\ in\ list})$ was *independent* of $N$; however, $N\mathrm{\ in\ list}$ implies a distribution of list sizes *dependent* on $N$.

So, we really only need to figure out $P(N\ \mathrm{chosen}|N\mathrm{\ in\ list})$. We can think of selection from the list as choosing the first $X$ names from a permutation of that list.

Therefore:

$P(N\ \mathrm{chosen}|N\mathrm{\ in\ list})=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(\mathrm{list\ is\ size\ }k|N\mathrm{\ in\ list})P(N\mathrm{\ is\ in\ first\ }X|\mathrm{list\ is\ size\ }k\wedge N\mathrm{\ in\ list})\tag{2}$

- We can say that $P(N\mathrm{\ is\ in\ first\ }X|\mathrm{list\ is\ size\ }k\wedge N\mathrm{\ in\ list})=\frac{X}{\max{\{X,k\}}}$, i.e., how probable it is that $N$ occurs before the $X$ mark in the list. (This assumes that we just stop the selection process if we run out of names.)
- The distribution of possible list sizes must be determined from the per-name probabilities. This is a bit more complicated, because names with a probability of $1.0$ impose strict constraints, whereas we need to avoid treating them specially.

So overall we have:

$P(N\mathrm{\ chosen})=P(N\mathrm{\ in\ list})\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{X}{\max{\{X,k\}}}P(\mathrm{list\ is\ size\ }k|N\mathrm{\ in\ list})\tag{3}$

The best case is that all names have the same probability $p$, in which case $P(\mathrm{list\ is\ size\ }k|N\mathrm{\ in\ list})$ is just $k-1\sim B(n-1,p)$. I think the general case would be the Poisson binomial distribution excluding name $N$. (Probably $O(2^n)$ to compute.)

Comment: I would hazard a guess that "$N$ in list" and "list is size $k$" are not independent events.

Comment: @Chrystomath Good point; however, $P(N\ \mathrm{chosen}|N\mathrm{\ in\ list})$ is independent of $N$. This means that the summation either can't depend on $N$ or it must coincidentally be equal for every $N$. So, maybe my summation has an error.

Comment: Actually, what I just said isn't true, because $N\mathrm{\ in\ list}$ implies a distribution of list sizes dependent on $N$.